# Running Flutter Application Directly In IOS Devices

Tags: ios, flutter

I am new to Flutter IOS. I am trying to run directly in my iPhone/iPad . I was able to run successfully when i tried in simulators. Is there anything to do manually to achieve this. More over I am getting an error dialog, when i was trying to run
[image]

```html
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           20.6s
Installing and launching...
Connecting to the VM Service is taking longer than expected...
Still attempting to connect to the VM Service...
If you do NOT see the Flutter application running, it might have crashed. The device logs (e.g. from adb or XCode) might have more details.
If you do see the Flutter application running on the device, try re-running with --host-vmservice-port to use a specific port known to be available.
```